# Stacking views changing size weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stackview

I have set the constraints for two views correctly and the preview for different devices is good. I even used size class for changing the aspect ratio for iPads [image: Preview with constraints sets before stacking]

Now when I stack these two views, the size of the resulting stack changes dramatically. [image: weird size changes after stacking]

Why the size of the resulting stack is weird in this case?

I am a beginner in iOS programming and would appreciate any help here.